# Detecting language using Stanford NLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm wondering if it is possible to use `Stanford CoreNLP` to detect which language a sentence is written in? If so, how precise can those algorithms be?

Comment: You might be interested in [The WiLI benchmark dataset for written language identification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07779) paper.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost certainly there is no language identification in Stanford COreNLP at this moment. 'almost' - because nonexistence is much harder to prove.

EDIT: Nevertheless, below are circumstantial evidences:

1. there is no mention of language identification neither on [main
   page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/), nor [CoreNLP page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), nor in [FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp-faq.shtml#languages) (although there is
   a question 'How do I run CoreNLP on other languages?'), nor in [2014
   paper](http://www.surdeanu.info/mihai/papers/acl2014-corenlp.pdf) of CoreNLP's authors;
2. tools that combine several NLP libs
   including Stanford CoreNLP use another lib for language
   identification, for example [DKPro Core ASL](http://blog.newitfarmer.com/tags/stanford-corenlp%E2%80%A0); also [other
   users](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2013-March/003133.html) talking about language identification and CoreNLP don't mention this capability
3. source file of CoreNLP contains `Language`
   classes, but nothing related to language identification - you can
   check manually for all 84 occurrence of 'language' word [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=language%20site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fmavenbrowse.pauldoo.com%2Fcentral%2Fedu%2Fstanford%2Fnlp%2Fstanford-corenlp%2F3.4%2Fstanford-corenlp-3.4-javadoc.jar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=language%20site:http://mavenbrowse.pauldoo.com/central/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.4/stanford-corenlp-3.4-javadoc.jar&start=30)

Try [TIKA](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_language_detection.htm), or [TextCat](http://textcat.sourceforge.net/), or [Language Detection Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) (they report "99% over precision for 53 languages").

In general, quality depends on the size of input text: if it is long enough (say, at least several words and not specially chosen), then precision can be pretty good - about 95%.

Answer (score 11):

Standford CoreNLP doesn't have language ID (at least not yet), see http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

---

There are loads more on language detection/identification tools. But do take the reported precision with a pinch of salt. It is usually evaluated narrowly, bounded by:

- a fix list of languages,
- a substantial length of the test sentences and
- of the same language and
- a skewed proportion of training to testing instances.

---

**Notable language ID tools** includes:

- TextCat (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textcat/index.html)
- CLD2 (https://code.google.com/p/cld2/)
- LingPipe (http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/langid/read-me.html)
- LangID (https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py)
- CLD3 (https://github.com/google/cld3)

**An exhaustive list** from meta-guide.com, see http://meta-guide.com/software-meta-guide/100-best-github-language-identification/

---

**Noteworthy Language Identification related shared task** (with training/testing data) includes:

- [Native Language ID (NLI 2013)](https://sites.google.com/site/nlisharedtask2013/home)
- [Discriminating Similar Languages (DSL 2014)](http://corporavm.uni-koeln.de/vardial/sharedtask.html)
- [TweetID (2015)](http://komunitatea.elhuyar.org/tweetlid/)

---

**Also take a look** at:

- [Language Identification: The Long and the Short of the Matter](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N10-1027.pdf)
- [The Problems of Language Identification within Hugely Multilingual Data Sets](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/138760/Xia-Lewis-Lewis.pdf)
- [Selecting and Weighting N-Grams to Identify 1100 Languages](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-40585-3_60)
- [Indigenous Tweets](http://indigenoustweets.blogspot.de/2011/12/1000-languages-on-web.html)
- [Microblog Language Identification: Overcoming the Limitations of Short, Unedited and Idiomatic Text](http://scarter.org/papers/lrev-lid.pdf)

Comment: There's also a Language detection module in Apache Tika : https://tika.apache.org/1.24.1/detection.html