# Language detection API/Library

Tags: api, nlp

Is there a service/library (free or paid) that takes a piece of text and return the language of it?

I need to go over a million blog posts and determine their languages.

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection?

Comment: see answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29290107/4588780

Answer (score 6):

I think this is the best out there!

https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about `langid.py`.

Features from the README:

> - Fast
> - Pre-trained over a large number of languages (currently 97)
> - Not sensitive to domain-specific features (e.g. HTML/XML markup)
> - Single .py file with minimal dependencies
> - Deployable as a web service

https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py