# Java, Stanford NLP : Extract specific speech labels from parser

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I recently discovered the Stanford NLP parser and it seems quite amazing. I have currently a working instance of it running in our project but facing the below mentioned 2 problems.

1. How can I parse text and then extract only specific speech-labels from the parsed data, for example, how can I extract only `NNPS` and `PRP` from the sentence.
2. Our platform works in both English and German, so there is always a possibility that the text is either in English or German. How can I accommodate this scenario. Thank you.

Code :

```
 private final String PCG_MODEL = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz";

    private final TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> tokenizerFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "invertible=true");

 public void testParser() {
  LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(PCG_MODEL);
        String sent="Complete Howto guide to install EC2 Linux server in Amazon Web services cloud.";
        Tree parse;
        parse = lp.parse(sent);

        List taggedWords = parse.taggedYield();
        System.out.println(taggedWords);
}
```

The above example works, but as you can see I am loading the English data. Thank you.

Comment: Refer here - http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml

Comment: @SrikanthA : Thank you, from point-24, I understand that there is fallback mechanism incase the language is wrong. Any idea about the first issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    for (Tree subTree: parse) // traversing the sentence's parse tree 
    {
      if(subTree.label().value().equals("NNPS")) //If the word's label is NNPS
       { //Do what you want }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Query 1, I don't think stanford-nlp has an option to extract a specific POS tags.

However, Using custom trained models, we can achieve the same. I had tried similar requirement for NER - name Entity recognition custom models.

Comment: Thank you. Am I right about Query-2 where it will fallback to German or do I have to do language-detection first?

Comment: For Query -2, You may have to look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290107/detecting-language-using-stanford-nlp and http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp-faq.shtml#languages. 
Note - I have not tried multi language, but see if above links helps